Possible to override MAUI's dependency injection?
I have a dependency injection framework used for an ASP.NET project. I'd like to use the same code for a new MAUI project but am having trouble finding a way to insert my DI container into the built in MAUI way of doing things.
In ASP.NET core I'd be able to implement IControllerActivator (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers) which would give me a chance to build the controller the way I want to on every request. Is there some equivalent interface for ContentPage/ContentView for MAUI?

You can check this document about the Dependency injection in Maui.
